# Append checksum value in trailer

Tags: shell-script

I want to append SHA256 checksum hash value to trailer record of a file

`file1.txt`

```
H this is a test 
D 1
D 2
D 3
T checksum
```

Used below command to obtain 64 digit alpha numeric hash value

`sha256sum file1.txt >file2.txt`

`file2.txt`

```
<64digituniquealphanumvalue> file1.txt
```

My expected output file would be

`file3.txt`

```
H this is a test
D 1
D 2
D 3
T checksum <64digituniquealphanum>
```

But I got the below output using below command

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

`file3.txt`

```
H this is a test
D 1
D 2
D 3
T checksum
<64digituniquealphanum> file1.txt
```

`file1` has a new line and my requirement is to append the 64 digit unique checksum hash value in T record type that is last line of file in unix without filename as given in expected file format. Kindly advise me with the commands how to achieve it in unix

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain your use case in more detail. How do you plan to check the checksum? To get the same checksum again you would have to remove the checksum value and the separating space first. `sed "s/T checksum/& $(sha256sum file1.txt|cut -f1 -d\ )/" file1.txt > file3.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed "s/^T checksum$/& $(sha256sum file1.txt | awk '{print $1}')/" file1.txt
```

This `sed` command matches the line in `file1.txt` that consists solely of "T checksum", then appends it with a space followed by the sha256 digest of `file1.txt`.

Given your `file1.txt`, it will output:

```
H this is a test
D 1
D 2
D 3
T checksum 521967963f10f7f980c96ee7dfc832035d5fff252b134958add8a323023364d5
```

Note that if the "T checksum" line in `file1.txt` has *anything* else on it (ie, an extra space or whatever), it would not match the `^T checksum$` pattern and nothing would be appended to it.

Answer (score 0):

The `sed`  "`e`" command is not available on all versions, here on linux with `sed (GNU sed) 4.7`, try

```
sed -e '$ { h;s/.*/sha256sum file/; e ' -e '; s/ .*$//; H; x; s/\n/ /}' file
H this is a test 
D 1
D 2
D 3
T checksum 0ad6aaad4fea8e27b8c270191a43e1f8f12113e7b9dc34fecd7fcee053b42604
```

The last line is saved to hold space, then `sha256sum` is executed on the input file and appended to hold space which then is exchanged to pattern space, the `<NL>` char removed, and printed.

Be aware that having appended to the file future checksum verifications will fail.

With your `file2` available, try

```
sed '1{s/ .*$//; h; d; }; ${G; s/\n/ /}' file2 file1
```